# Let user download file he cant access over the URL, but is stored on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

***Description:***

I'm using vb.net and jquery and try to let the user download a file (files are images or pdf-files).

The thing I'm trying to do is that the user can download the files, but can't access the files over the URL.

I'm new to vb.net and don't know if I'm walking the right path with my solution (obviously because I don't get it to work), I ask for solution ideas, helpful hints/links and a bit of kindness, I'm a bit frustrated

**My current, not working Solution:**

The Files are located in a Directory that's the same as the Directory of my web application (so -> c:/.../files  and  c:/.../webapp)

I made a virtual directory over the IIS to access the folder 
(c:/.../webapp/f -> c:/.../files)

So now I'm trying to do an ajax request from my "a.aspx" to my "a.aspx.vb"

```vb
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=foo.jpg")
Response.TransmitFile("C:/.../webapp/f/foo.jpg")
Response.End()
```

This snippet works if I put it the `Page_Load` Sub. Out of the `Page_Load` Sub, I receive the Error "Response not available in the current context"

```
var d = {
    "path": "c:/.../webapp/f/foo.jpg"
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "a.aspx/DownloadFile",
    data: JSON.stringify(d),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("success");
    },
    failure: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        alert("fail");
    },
    error: function (xhr, err) {
        console.log(err);
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

With the AJAX request version, I no longer use the vb.net code in the `Page_Load` Sub

```vb
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function DownloadFile(path As String) As String
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & path.Split("/")(path.Split("/").Length - 1))
    Response.TransmitFile(path)
    Response.End()
    Return path.Split("/")(path.Split("/").Length - 1)
End Function
```

I really appreciate that you read my question, thank you in advance

**P.S.** It's my first post here, please don't be harsh if I did mistakes and tell me kindly what I did wrong

---

**EDIT:**

I now use FileSaver.js, I got it to work and that I can download the files, but only if I don't hide the directory that includes the files. This solution still isn't working for me because I still can access the files even if I'm not allowed to. I'm still missing something and kindly ask again for more information and more help, thanks in advance!

(all still hardcoded)

***Javascript:***

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(xhr.response);
    saveAs(xhr.response, "file.pdf"); //this is a FileSaver.js Function
}
xhr.send();
```

***VB.NET Code:***

```vb
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="DownloadHandler" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services

Public Class DownloadHandler : Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Dim path As String
        path = context.Server.MapPath("~/upload/media/file/file.pdf")

        Dim file As New System.IO.FileInfo(path)
        If file.Exists Then
            context.Response.Clear()
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & file.Name)
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString())
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            context.Response.WriteFile(file.FullName)
            context.Response.End()
        Else
            context.Response.Write("This file does not exist.")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: 1) You can set a directory to be off-limits to clients in IIS. In IIS Manager, navigate to the site in the left pane. Open the "Request Filtering"  part under the "IIS" section in the middle. Choose the "Hidden Segments" tab up at the top. Under "Actions" on the right, choose "Add Hidden Segment...". Unfortunately the "..." in the question has hidden the parts that would have shown me what you would need to enter. 2) Next, just use the filename in the request, not the whole path, to request the file from an .ashx handler.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I already had the hidden Directory, but how I explained in my last Edit (09.09.2019) it got me in trouble sadly.

I'm sorry for the late respond

Comment: What determines if the user is allowed to download a file?

Comment: @AndrewMorton only a user that's logged in is allowed to download.

if I don't hide the directory I could just open up the URL where the image or other file is stored and download it this way, without logging in.

Comment: You could check that the user is logged in as the first thing in `Public Sub ProcessRequest`. Also, 1) You can do a proper 404 with `context.Response.StatusCode = 404` `context.Response.StatusDescription = "File not found."`. 2) If you use `context.Response.TransmitFile(file.Name)` (not FullName) then you don't need to set the content length. 3) Look up the documentation for `Response.End()` - it is not what you want to do.